# What can I do with the files of a Notion electron app on my machine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

I have installed Notion for desktop and as far as I know, it's an Electron app. I opened the file location of the app. I opened the folder `AppData\Local\Programs\Notion\resources\app` on VSCode. Here's the folder structure:

```
app
├── helpers
├── i18n
├── main
├── node_modules
├── renderer
├── shared
├── config.js
├── config.json
├── forge.config.extra.json
├── forge.config.js
├── icon.ico
├── module.json
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── tsconfig.build.json
├── tsconfig.forgeconfig.json
├── tsconfig.json
└── tsconfig.tsbuildinfo
```

I opened the package.json file and find:

```
{
  "name": "Notion",
  "author": "Notion Labs, Inc",
  "version": "2.0.53",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Notion",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.8.3",
    "@sentry/electron": "2.5.4",
    "better-sqlite3": "8.5.0",
    "bufferutil": "4.0.3",
    "chroma-js": "2.1.2",
    "csp_evaluator": "1.1.0",
    "electron-log": "4.4.8",
    "electron-store": "8.1.0",
    "electron-updater": "4.1.2",
    "electron-window-state": "5.0.3",
    "fflate": "0.7.4",
    "fs-extra": "8.1.0",
    "get-port": "5.1.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.15",
    "notion-intl": "file:shared/notion-intl",
    "react": "16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "16.10.2",
    "react-intl": "3.11.0",
    "ws": "7.4.1"
  },
  "main": "./main/main.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "6.1.1",
    "@electron-forge/core": "6.1.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-dmg": "6.1.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "6.1.1",
    "@electron-forge/shared-types": "6.1.1",
    "@felixrieseberg/electron-forge-maker-nsis": "6.0.6",
    "@types/ws": "7.4.0",
    "electron": "25.2.0"
  },
  "files": [
    "*.js",
    "*.html"
  ],
  "productName": "Notion"
}
```

I was curious so I did `npm install` and then used the command `npm start`
The console shows:

```
> Notion@2.0.53 start
> electron-forge start

✔ Checking your system
✔ Locating application
⠋ Loading configuration
◼ Preparing native dependencies
◼ Running generateAssets hook
```

[image: screenshot]

Nothing happens afterwards.

Can I even run the app?
P.S- I'm a CS noob.